# Parse between comments in Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, html-parsing

Can I fetch the data between two html comments using Simple HTML Dom ??

For example, See the below code:

```
<!-- start of comment -->

<a href="link1.html" target="_blank">link1</a><br />
<a href="link2.html" target="_blank">link2</a><br />
<a href="link3.html" target="_blank">link3</a><br />
<a href="link4.html" target="_blank">link4</a><br />


<!-- end of comment-->

<a href="link5.html" target="_blank">link5</a><br />
<a href="link6.html" target="_blank">link6</a><br />
```

There are totally six links and only 4 links are enclosed within a "" and "" tags.

I just want to get the links between the comment tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($elements as $child) {
    echo $child->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This returns *all* anchors, not only the ones between comments

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
//get all comments
$comments = $html->find('comment');
```

...and use `next_sibling()` to get next element and check if it's an anchor tag till you get another comment tag, where the script will terminate.